# How to create event driven class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

i'm kinda curious how dart class and constructor work
i saw Bloc implementation in bloc Firebase Login Doc

```
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppState> {
  AppBloc({required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository})
      : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        super(
          authenticationRepository.currentUser.isNotEmpty
              ? AppState.authenticated(authenticationRepository.currentUser)
              : const AppState.unauthenticated(),
        ) {
    on<_AppUserChanged>(_onUserChanged);
    on<AppLogoutRequested>(_onLogoutRequested);
    _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user.listen(
      (user) => add(_AppUserChanged(user)),
    );
  }

  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
  late final StreamSubscription<User> _userSubscription;

  void _onUserChanged(_AppUserChanged event, Emitter<AppState> emit) {
    emit(
      event.user.isNotEmpty
          ? AppState.authenticated(event.user)
          : const AppState.unauthenticated(),
    );
  }

  void _onLogoutRequested(AppLogoutRequested event, Emitter<AppState> emit) {
    unawaited(_authenticationRepository.logOut());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

how to create class **(with on)** like this i know it's inherit, but when i saw that, damn! it's best use for Event Driven

```
{
  on<_AppUserChanged>(_onUserChanged);
  on<AppLogoutRequested>(_onLogoutRequested);
  _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user.listen(
    (user) => add(_AppUserChanged(user)),
  );
}
```

how to implements such interface?